# Printing a generator in python tensor flow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the `tensor flow` tutorial as described in this [link](https://github.com/random-forests/tutorials/blob/master/ep7.ipynb)

I am trying to print the predicted result as described :

```
print ("Predicted %d, Label: %d" % (classifier.predict(test_data[0]), test_labels[0]))
```

But I am not able to print the result. I am getting the following error.

```
    print ("Predicted %d, Label: %d" % (classifier.predict(test_data[0]), test_labels[0]))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not generator
```

How do I print the `generator` in `python`.

I tried to write a loop and iterate over the elements it didn't work and I tried to use `next` to print the generator. That also didn't work. How do I print it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved it

```
new_samples = np.array([test_data[8]], dtype=float)

y = list(classifier.predict(new_samples, as_iterable=True))
print('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))

print ("Predicted %s, Label: %d" % (str(y), test_labels[8]))
```

Comment: @jgm Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

No `tensorflow` here, so let's mock up a generator and test it against your `print` expression

```
In [11]: def predict(a, b):
    ...:     for i in range(10):
    ...:         yield i, i*i
    ...:         

In [12]: print('a:%d, b:%d'%(predict(0, 0)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-29ec761936ef> in <module>()
----> 1 print('a:%d, b:%d'%(predict(0, 0)))

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not generator
```

So far, so good: I have the same problem that you've experienced.

The problem is, of course, that what you get when you call a generator function are not values but a generator object...

You have to iterate on the generator objects, using whatever is returned from each iteration, e.g.,

```
In [13]: print('\n'.join('a:%d, b:%d'%(i,j) for i, j in predict(0,0)))
a:0, b:0
a:1, b:1
a:2, b:4
a:3, b:9
a:4, b:16
a:5, b:25
a:6, b:36
a:7, b:49
a:8, b:64
a:9, b:81
```

or, if you don't like one-liners,

```
In [14]: for i, j in predict(0, 0):
    ...:     print('a:%d, b:%d'%(i,j))
    ...:     
a:0, b:0
a:1, b:1
a:2, b:4
a:3, b:9
a:4, b:16
a:5, b:25
a:6, b:36
a:7, b:49
a:8, b:64
a:9, b:81
```

In other words, you have *to explicitly consume* what the generator is producing.

Comment: I tried out both your methods. But now I get another error.

`for i,j in predict(0, 0):   # error here 
    print('a:%d, b:%d'%(i,j))`

`TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`

Comment: I've tested my examples with python 3.5.2 and python 2.7.13 and the behavior is exactly what I've reported in my answer — `predict` is a callable object that **returns** a generator object and in my code I never tried to call the returned generator object.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/estimators#LinearClassifier.predict):

> Runs inference to determine the class probability predictions.
>   (deprecated arguments)
>
> SOME ARGUMENTS ARE DEPRECATED. They will be removed after 2016-09-15.
>   Instructions for updating: The default behavior of predict() is
>   changing. The default value for as_iterable will change to True, and
>   then the flag will be removed altogether. The behavior of this flag is
>   described below.

Try:

```
classifier.predict(x=test_data[0])
```

Comment: @Maximillan I tried as you told `print ("Predicted %d, Label: %d" % (classifier.predict(x=test_data[0]), test_labels[0]))`, but still I get the same error .  `print ("Predicted %d, Label: %d" % (classifier.predict(x=test_data[0]), test_labels[0]))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not generator`

Comment: Can you try without %d and see what it prints?

Comment: When I try it like this `print classifier.predict(x=test_data[0])` I get the following error `<generator object _as_iterable at 0x7f34bc1ca870>`