# How to get predicted out put in DNNLinearCombinedRegressor

Tags: tensorflow

I understand that using its function `predict_scores` I can generate a iterator object and it can output all the predictions for the input. However, is there a way to simply get all the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you've solved this by now but jgm's answer below did it for me:

[Printing a generator in python tensor flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611518/printing-a-generator-in-python-tensor-flow)